# Setting up and running CGMiner on a Raspberry Pi for a Jalapeño

Tags: cgminer

I have a BFL Jalapeño miner and a Raspberry Pi and I would like to get the Jalapeño to run off of CGMiner from the Raspberry Pi, however, I am not quite sure how to do this.

Doing some research, I came across this guide: http://dominustemporis.com/2013/06/compiling-cgminer-for-the-raspberry-pi-and-butterflylabs-jalapeno/

I am unable to install most of the prerequisites and Im pretty sure it's because they are no longer available or can't be reached for some other reason. I am running the newest version of Raspbian and I ran apt-get update. How can I get CGMiner to install and run on my Raspberry Pi for my Jalapeño?

Comment: So many foodstuffs!

Comment: @Lodewijk I know! Seems like they shouldn't be compatible based on their culinary properties. Hopefully this doesn't carry over ;P

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using [bfgminer](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer), and [so does Butterfly Labs](http://butterflylabs.com/drivers/).  Well, I guess they say cgminer will work, too :P.

The 4.10/4.3 branch, as well as the latest/master branch, work especially well with the Jalapeños and the Monarchs.

#### [Build Instructions](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README)

1. `sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libcurl4-gnutls-dev   libjansson-dev uthash-dev libncursesw5-dev libudev-dev libusb-1.0-0-dev libevent-dev libmicrohttpd-dev hidapi`
2. `git clone https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer && cd bfgminer`
3. `./autogen.sh`
4. `./configure`
5. `make`
6. `make install`

#### Notes

Once you've gotten it to build and work successfully, take a look at the `./configure` options and remove any unnecessary drivers/options for efficiency :D

Comment: Do you which option should I use for USB Antminer U1 or U2  ? also I manage installed the bfgminer on my raspberry pi4, but It said : No servers could be used! Exiting. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try finding a binary version of CGMiner, or downloading CGminer from a repository for your chosen distro. [From here](https://github.com/kanoi/cgminer-binaries) for example. I should note that binaries are (even) less safe than compiling from (unread/unchecked) source.

There is also a great deal of tutorials available when searching for "Raspberry cgminer" on Google, and I doubt any tutorial that's written just for this question will do better than one of those.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do more research. I have realized that I have always been looking specifically for tutorials about Jalapeños when it is unnecessary. Also, How would I go about downloading and installing from the source you linked to?

Comment: There's several ways to download the archive(s) from the GitHub website, you can just browse towards the required file and click it for example. This is your link: https://github.com/kanoi/cgminer-binaries/blob/master/3.1.1/cgminer-3.1.1-x86_64-built.tar.bz2 . You'd then extract it and run it.

If this is too hard it may be better to hook the Jalapeno up to a Windows machine for now, and learn how to use Unix, Git, Make, etc. in whatever time you have. Then hook it up to the Pi when you know how. You need fundamentals to make using Raspberries interesting and fun. Now it will just frustrate!